# moving SpriteNode method from gamescene to own class file for first time, node not drawing

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to move a method from my main GameScene to a new file/class for the first time, so I can keep things cleaner, really just trying to keep the code the same as much as possible and just put it in its own file in the project.

It's a SKSpriteNode method, once I set it up I can see my NSLog showing up but I can't get the node itself to be drawn to the screen, I must be doing something wrong with how I'm creating/assigning/pointing to this spritenode in this new file/class or something?

If someone could spare a sec and have a look and help me understand any help would be fantastic

Currently in GameScene.m I do this method like

```
@implementation GameScene
{
SKSpriteNode *myNode;
}

//own method in GameScene
- (SKSpriteNode *)createMyNode
{
myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
myNode.position = CGPointMake(50, 50);
//etc
return myNode;
}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
[self addChild: [self createMyNode]];
}

//it then is successfully created on screen
```

Now I'm trying to add the above into a new file/class it's own file etc

```
newclassfile.m
#import "newclassfile.h"

@implementation newclassfile {
SKSpriteNode myNode
}

- (SKSpriteNode *)createMyNode 
{
myNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
myNode.position = CGPointMake(50, 50);
//etc
NSLog(@"newclassfile myNode check");
return myNode;
}


newclassfile.h
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface newclassfile : SKSpriteNode

-(SKSpriteNode*)createMyNode;

@end
```

then back at GameScene.m

```
//import header
#import "newclassfile.h"


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
newclassfile *myNode=[[newclassfile alloc]init];
[myNode createMyNode];
}
```

I hope to see my new spritenode but don't see it, I do however see the  NSLog(@"newclassfile myNode check"); in console which tells me the method is being run I guess.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newclassfile.h, add the following method prototypes

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface newclassfile : SKSpriteNode

+ (instancetype) createMyNode;
+ (instancetype) spriteNodeWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size;
- (id) initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size;

@end
```

In newclassfile.m, declare a method to initialize a sprite node and a convenience methods to alloc/init a new node.

```
#import "newclassfile.h"

@implementation newclassfile

+ (instancetype) createMyNode
{
    return [[newclassfile alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
}

+ (instancetype) spriteNodeWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    return [[newclassfile alloc] initWithColor:color size:size];
}

- (id) initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self=[super initWithColor:color size:size]) {
        self.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
        // Create a physics body
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size]; 
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

in GameViewController.m, change the following

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
```

to this

```
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
```

and lastly in GameScene.m, create a new sprite node with

```
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    newclassfile *myNode = [newclassfile createMyNode];
    [self addChild:myNode];
}
```

Comment: Hi @0x141E thanks for the reply! Gee wiz thats a lot of work to just put a method in another file isn't it! Is that just how things work when dealing with new files/classes etc? No simpler way to do it?

This code does work but say I wanted to make this node also become a  physicsBody how do I do that now? Was hoping I could just do something like

//your code
if (self=[super initWithColor:color size:size]) {
        self.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
//my physicsbody code here
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(35, 35)];

but I guess it's not that simple?